# Sending string/data via php to device connected to my server

Tags: php, tcp, udp, wifi, arduino

Good Day,

I have a hardware device (an RN-XV WiFi chip) which has successfully connected to my server IP address through port 80. I am able to send junk data and it responds with a "server is unable to serve this request", meaning there is a connection.

Now, I need to talk to this device/send it data/strings. I know some basic PHP, but I have no idea how to approach this problem. My device is connected to the server but:

1. To send data to it, I have to know the IP/Port of the device connected right? How do I find that out?
2. If I am able to obtain this..is sending data a matter of opening a TCP connection via PHP and sending a string?
3. Now that I am connected to the server, I am somehow able to send strings, but it returns with a server unable to serve this request. How do I actually send data to a particular PHP file to read?

Please Help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is intended use? It will help us visualize your problem.

Comment: just testing communication between a server and a device thats all. for my embedded systems project.

Comment: yeah, but are you trying to send a command to the wireless device or use the wireless device to command something else? What is its function?

Answer (score 1):

you must write program  for socket .see this page for php socket programming  http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

with this function you can connect to every port , send data and get response with every format that you want .

sample:for connect to Device

```
<?php
    $fp = fsockopen("udp://127.0.0.1", 2000, $errno, $errstr);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
    } else {
       fwrite($fp, "data for send");
       while ( !feof( $fp ) ) { 
          $ret .= fgets( $fp, 4096 ); 
       }
       echo $ret;
       fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

more sample http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: Okay please answer this. My device is connected to my server, and if I want to use socket programming TCP or UDP..i need the IP address of my device! How on earth do I find this out?

I only have the IP address of the device connected to my wireless network. what is the address of my device on the server?!

Comment: @user1436508 when php and device is on one server for connect to device use 127.0.0.1 ip is for inside of server

Comment: localhost is point to your php server that you run php on it .you can use it for connect to anther device and service on php server .

Comment: ARGH!

please my question is very simple. my device is now listening to any/all responses sent via UDP from my server from say port 2000. it is configured like that.

the problem is..what address do i send the UDP data to in the php script!? I cant send it to localhost right? I need to send it to my device! What do i do?

Comment: @user1436508 I Put One Sample for it see.

Comment: thanks for the sample, but I dont understand what is happening. i ran it with a while loop and i tried to send responses from my device but nothing happens. does this code running in a loop accept all responses coming to this server from port 2k?

Comment: @user1436508 yes size of data not important  . see changed sample.

Comment: it seems my port 2000 is closed. when i try to telet to it..it says connect failed. other ports like 80 work. how can i open port 2000? it is an apache server. what file do i modify?

Comment: @user1436508 are you sure device is on port 2000  is run?.if it is run must work .see the run service list for sure about it.

Comment: it works when i do it locally on the same wifi, but if i attempt to send it to my web server add..no response

Comment: Also use lsusb, lspci, netstat commands to check device using which port on your system.

Comment: @user1436508 you mean device and php server is on different computer?

Comment: its okay i figured it out my server did not accept non standard ports

Comment: what you mean non standard ports? server only did not accept port. when port is full